# C++ Static Const Member Variable Usage

Tags: c++, static, constants, member

Say that I have a class that requires a few constants to function.  Several member functions require use of these constants.  Use of #define is frowned upon since it can cause collisions.  The constants are hex patterns of 8 or 16 bits and are stored as uint8_t or uint16_t.  These constants also don't change from instance to instance of the class, and therefore memory (albeit very little memory)  can be saved by having only one copy of the constants.

Is there anything improper, or perhaps of better way of accomplishing the above instead of simply doing something like the following:

```
// mycode.h
// .......
class myclass {
private:
  static const uint16_t kMyClassConstant_ = 0xBEEF;
// .......
};
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong with that. (Hopefully some of the C++ experts won't have to correct me. :)   )

Comment: You might get better answers at http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Yes, it is a normal way of declaring a global constant.

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding the other site!

Comment: This is fine; integral constants can also be created in a namespace-safe way as `enums`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Given your description of the situation, I'd say using `static const` members is a good approach. In C++11 you may want to change it into `static constexpr` to emphasize it's a compile-time constant, although nothing will effectively change as a result of that.

If you refer to `myclass::kMyClassContant_` somewhere in the code in a way that is relevant under the one-definition-rule (odr), esp. in contexts that require a reference (including const-reference), the compiler will complain that there is no definition of the constant. Merely declaring and initializing it inside the class isn't sufficient in this case. This may force you to separate declaration and definition:

```
// mycode.h
class myclass {
private:
  static const uint16_t kMyClassConstant_;
};

// mycode.cpp
const uint16_t myclass::kMyClassConstant_ = 0xBEEF;
```

To avoid the trouble of maintaining separate declarations and definitions, some people prefer declaring an inline constexpr function instead of an actual variable:

```
// mycode.h
class myclass {
private:
  static constexpr uint16_t kMyClassConstant_()
  { return 0xBEEF; }
};
```

This is a correct work-around for many of the odr-related problems, and it does not cause any loss in performance. Whether it is really useful depends on how much of a burden it is to maintain separate declarations and definitions of an ordinary static constant. If you expect your constants to never change as your code evolves, using ordinary static constants with separate definitions is preferable. But if you modify the definitions of the constants frequently, having to re-compile the definition file and re-link it to all relevant parts of the project may make you consider the function-based solution above as a better alternative.

A final comment on the data type: Forcing it into 16 bits using `std::uint16_t` can be useful if you need to store lots of these values in compact form. Otherwise, the actual size may not really matter, in which case `std::uint_fast16_t` (which may be larger than 16 bits) may be better.

Comment: I've been paying attention to your answers in SO, and as far as I can tell they are the best in terms of clarification and precision. This contrasts with some individuals with high "reputation", who constantly appeal to mystification rather than answering the questions. Congratulations (+1)

Comment: @411165 Thanks for the praise :) I appreciate your thoroughness in studying my (and others') SO posts!

Comment: This answer is quite useful, but I don't get the reasoning about recompilation. I would think that using inline members functions (in the class definition and therefore in the header file), every change to the values would necessitate _recompilation_ of all client translation units (which include that header file), even though they cannot directly access those private member functions. On the other hand with separate declarations and definitions, changing the values only changes the implementation module, requiring a single recompilation and just _relinking_ of clients. That's less, not more.

Answer (score 5):

You could use type traits to implement this:

```
#include <type_traits>

class myclass {
private:
  typedef std::integral_constant<uint16_t , 0xBEEF> kMyClassConstant;

  // ...
};
```

used as `myclass::kMyClassConstant::value`.

This shows the purpose of implementing an integral constant and prevents you from accidentaly taking an address of the constant.

Answer (score 5):

Since C++17, we have access to `inline` variables, which take care of the odr-related problems. Several options:

```
// mycode.h
class myclass {
    static const inline uint16_t kMyClassConstant_ = 0xBEEF;
};
```

Or, if it can be marked `constexpr` (like in this case):

```
// mycode.h
class myclass {
    static constexpr inline uint16_t kMyClassConstant_ = 0xBEEF;
};
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
// mycode.h
class myclass {
    static constexpr uint16_t kMyClassConstant_ = 0xBEEF;
};
```

Because in C++17 `constexpr` implies `inline` for `static` data members.