# Linking Static Variable in Abstract Class

Tags: c++, r, gcc, rcpp

I am trying to build an R package with Rcpp. I encounter build error in Mac OS, but the build works fine in Windows.

After investigation, this seems to be an edge case related to how we can use static variables from an abstract class to initialize NumericVector objects.

A minimal reproducible example is the following. First, "Base.h" defines an abstract class

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// Abstract class
class Base
{
public:
    static const int GLOBAL = 4;
    Base(){};
    virtual NumericVector test()=0;
};
```

Next, "Test.h" defines a child class

```
#include "Base.h"
using namespace Rcpp;
class Test : public Base
{
public:
    Test() : Base(){};
    NumericVector test();
};
```

Finally, "Test.cpp" implements the method

```
#include "Test.h"
NumericVector Test::test()
{
    NumericVector x(Test::GLOBAL);
    NumericVector y(1);  // if I comment this line, build succeeds
    return (x);
}
```

The error I encounter when running "Clean and Rebuild" in RStudio in Mac OS is:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘atIndel’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
> unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/00LOCK-atIndel/00new/atIndel/libs/atIndel.so':
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/00LOCK-atIndel/00new/atIndel/libs/atIndel.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZN4Base6GLOBALE
> Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/00LOCK-atIndel/00new/atIndel/libs/atIndel.so
> Expected in: flat namespace

However, this package works fine in RStudio in Windows.

In addition, notice that in the method "test" I initialize two vectors. If I comment out the second vector, "y", the build succeeds. In other words, it seems fine that I initialize only one NumericVector based on the static variable of the abstract class, but as soon as I initialize additional NumericVector objects in the same method, build fails.

Wondering if someone can give suggestions on this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it work if you change `static const int GLOBAL = 4;` to `static const int GLOBAL;` and then create a `Base.cpp` file where you define the static? (With `#include "Base.h"` followed by `const int Base::GLOBAL = 4;`.)

Comment: It worked! However, do you know why it worked?

Comment: Then it's a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056882/c-static-const-member-variable-usage). See the answer there on why it happens. You should probably try to make it `static constexpr inline int GLOBAL = 4;` (omit `inline` if you're using C++17 as that's redundant there) and see if that works as well.